# Mitmproxy certificate installation inconsistency

Tags: certificate, ca, mitmproxy

I run multiple servers, 2 of which I have mitmproxy installed and running on. I use a mix of tsocks and mitmproxy to intercept a https request a game server makes, which works on the first 2 servers I have. Both of those other servers run on Ubuntu 22.04. On my 3rd server, running Debian 11, the mitmproxy certificates do not work. I install them to ca certificates like I did for both of my other servers, tsocks, etc... Yet it does not work. I tried running server 3 on the same ubuntu version as well, to no avail. The certificates seem to have some kind of inconsistency when installing, is there any known fix for this?

mitmproxy-ca.pem is copied to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` as `mitmproxy-ca.crt`
running `sudo update-ca-certificates` shows: 1 added, 0 removed. (after copying)

The error mitmproxy hands me is:
Client Handshake failed. The client may not trust the proxy's certificate for (domain)

I have tried factory resetting, 8 times, reinstalling mitmproxy and the game server each time. Putting the certificates in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/`

Comment: Are you sure all 3 servers are using the Linux certificate store as trust store? E.g. Python programs often use Python `certifi` package and thus ignore the certificates provided by the OS.

Comment: Yes, I am certain.